# Autofac exception with Import Cardinality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef, autofac

I'm using Autofac with MEF in my MVC website. Basically I've coded a plugin system for the website. Plugins are in a folder, I create a DirectoryCatalog and register it with Autofac.

I created another project to be my plugin and tested it.

Everything works as expected. I have the controllers imported fine, and I can navigate to the MVC areas in my plugin.

When I add a second plugin (basically the same, just different naming/namespacing) Autofac throws errors regarding cardinality.

`'exports' cannot contain more than one element when ImportDefinition.ImportCardinality is ImportCardinality.ZeroOrOne or ImportCardinality.ExactlyOne. Parameter name: exports`

I've checked my DirectoryCatalog and all the exports appear there. And I can navigate to controllers in my host fine, but when I navigate to controllers for my plugins that I get an error. If I remove one of the plugins, then everything works fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the exception? Do you have any IMPORTS that specify only one when there are multiple EXPORTS? It could be a problem with the imports part, not the exports part.

Comment: @Travis - This is the part I'm confused with. I don't have any Imports in my code. I'm using Autofac, so use the `RegisterComposablePartCatalog` method and give it a DirectoryCatalog to consume. Here's the really weird part though. I downloaded the Autofac source off github this morning so I could further debug the problem. Compiled and changed the references, and everything works just fine. Which is incredibly frustrating!! If I do get to the bottom of this I will post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting everything from your output folder(s) [the folder that you use to create the DirectoryCatalog].

This is only valid if you use Autofac.Integration.Mef.

We had the same problem, basically all developers had this error when checking out after an project has been renamed, and the solution was always the same: just delete the output folder.

Here's what's happening:

When creating the DirectoryCatalog, Mef searches for all the .dll files in the output folder. But the output folder might contain old, unwanted .dll files, because when you rebuild your solution, the files are not being deleted, the files are just being replaced, so if you rename an assembly from OldName.dll to NewName.dll, the output folder will contain two files instead of just one, and Mef might crash if both dlls have the same export.

This is actually normal, and it works as expected, the big problem is that weird error message that is thrown by Autofac.Integration.Mef. Mef would have thrown a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same error. Clearing my output folders didn't fix it.

Turns out my problem was in my Autofac registrations in the plugin.

I had duplicate .Exported entries similar to the below:

```
builder.RegisterType<FileStreamFactory>()
            .As<IFileStreamFactory>()
            .Exported(x => x.As<IFileStreamFactory>());
builder.RegisterType<XmlWriterFactory>()
            .As<IXmlWriterFactory>()
            .Exported(x => x.As<IFileStreamFactory>());
```

So, make sure to check all of your Autofac registrations for duplicates. Mine was because of some bad copy-cancer.